# How to add NSTableView to a CCLayer in cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nstableview

I'm developing an App. It is compatible with iOS and MacOS. Obviously I'm using preprocessing definitions to establish some code conditions. I'm using Cocos2D. (v.2.1)
My question is related to NSTableView. While in the iOS version I was able to create a UITableView from scratch without using any XIB, and added to the scene using [[[Director sharedInstance] view] addSubview: myTableView] and it worked, the MacOS version didn't.

I created the NSTableView, even an NSHeaderView, also I stablished the delegate protocols for NStableView and DataSource, and it is working, because in my logs, I can see how my app returns the rows, and enters into the method to populate the Table data. But there is not a pixel on the screen. I've got added one column. I'm aware that many people missed to add a column, and the populate methods are not called.

Does anyone know if is it mandatory to use a XIB to create an NSTableView and loaded as a subView with cocos2D? Nothing that I've tested worked to show the table on the screen.

Thank you very much.

Comment: on OSX it is simply rather tricky to add views on top of a GL view: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/04/display-nsview-top-cocos2d-iphone-opengl-view-mac/

Comment: Yes I'm aware about that page. The problem is in the latest OSX and Cocos2D 2.1 the NSView objects are located as an overlay. If you move the window or resize it, the objects appears floating over the window. It is really strange behaviour. :(